# Kotlin Array with named parameter equivalent of swift

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist

Hi i'am new to Kotlin and i would like to do an array with named parameter. In Swift i can do :

```
let analytics = ["organization_login": "toto", "organization_name": "titi", "lead_email": "tata"]
```

The type is : `[String: String]`

I Looked all Array and Arraylist in kotlin but i couln't find the equivalent.

What i want it's to be able to give parameter name for my array.

**Edit**

I misunderstood the swift syntaxe, it's seem that it's only a dictonary, so we just have to use map.

Comment: I'm not too sure about this swift construct, but it really looks like a `Map<String, String>`

Comment: Even in Swift, this isn't an array. It's a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html) as

```
val map = mapOf("organization_login" to "toto", "organization_name" to "titi") 
// immutable map
```

you can also use `sortedMapOf`, `hashMapOf` `linkedMapOf` etc for different algo based storage.

Note: If you want to add more elements later then make sure to use `mutableMapOf`

Comment: Thanks it's what i wanted

Comment: I am glad that I could help, Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `[String: String]` is not an array, it's a [Dictionary](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113).

The equivalent of Dictionary in Kotlin is [Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html).

Maps can be created like so:

```
val map = mapOf("string_one" to "string_2", "string_3" to "string_4")
```

or, if you want to mutate it:

```
val mutableMap = mutableMapOf("string_one" to "string_2")
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out: unlike an Array, a Map is unordered.  So if you need the mappings to be in a particular order, you should either use a particular implementation (such as LinkedHashMap) that preserves iteration order, or use something else.  (Similarly, you can't have multiple mappings for the same key; that's a multi-map.)  Finally, you can't access mappings by index; instead, you look up the value for a particular key, e.g. `map["string_one"]` (or, equivalently, `map.get("string_one")`) which returns `"string_2"`.